# Export a style from Mapbox Studio to be used in Mabox GL-JS

Tags: style, mapbox

I designed my map with Mapbox Studio.

However I would like to use my design in Mapbox gl-js. The styles are not CartoCSS but a JSON.
Is there a way to export my design to this JSON format?

They seem very close, so I guess I could write a converter, but I would require some time, and I didn’t find all the features in the JSON format (for instance selecting with a regex).

Comment: no, it doesn't look like it's possible to produce mapbox-gl JSON styles in MapBox Studio at the moment.  Wouldn't be surprised if this shows up in a future version...

Comment: Ok thanks. Now I have to think if I wait or try to do it by hand :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MapBox now provides this feature. On the menu for mapbox studio with all your maps, you can download styles directly. [image]